# Regex to match different variants of string?

Tags: php, regex

Trying to find one regex which can handle/break up different variants of a string, such as:

//Standard variant with quote and space delimited

```
{"1" "TEXT"} //To break into 1 and TEXT
{"1" "TEXT" "2" "TEXT2"} //To break into 1, TEXT, 2 and TEXT2
{"1" "TEXT" "2" "TEXT2" "3" "TEXT3"} //To break into 1, TEXT, 2, TEXT2, 3 and TEXT3 etc etc
```

Above handled with:

```
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $string, $matches)
```

//How to handle the variant below

```
{1 "TEXT"} //Partial no quote. To break into 1 and TEXT
```

Comment: May be you need: `(?:\{|(?<!\A)\G)\h*\"?(\d+)"?\h+"(\w+)"(?=[^{}]*})`

Comment: My bad, meant quote not hyphen

Answer (score 2):

You may try this regex in PHP with `\G`:

```sh
(?:\{|(?<!\A)\G)\h*"?(\d+)"?\h+"([^"]*)"(?=[^{}]*})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dtnF0x/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\{`: Match opening `{`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?<!\A)\G`: Start from end of the previous match.
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\h*`: Match 0+ whitespaces
- `"?(\d+)"?`: Match and capture 1+ digits in group #1 wrapped in optional quotes
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `"([^"]*)"`: Match and capture 0+ non-quoted text in group #2 wrapped in quotes
- `(?=[^{}]*})`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a `}` ahead

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence number text number text is strictly adhered to, use this here:

```
$str = '{1 "TEXT" "2" "TEXT 2" 3 "TEXT3"}';

$r = preg_match_all('~"?(\d+)"? "([^"}]+)" ?~',$str,$match);

var_export($match);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => "1 \"TEXT\" ",
    1 => "\"2\" \"TEXT 2\" ",
    2 => "3 \"TEXT3\"",
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => "1",
    1 => "2",
    2 => "3",
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => "TEXT",
    1 => "TEXT 2",
    2 => "TEXT3",
  ),
)
```